# Service startet, but executet program not running proberly

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, services

I've created a Service on Windows Server 2008 R2, wich simply executes an exe.

Startup type: Automatic

Log on as: This account(a network account)

When I start the exe manually, all works fine. My problem now is, that after a reboot, the service status is `started` and also in Task Manager I see the service and also my exe as running(exe uses less Memory than usually), but the exe does not run properly(it is a backend and the frontend can't connect to it). After restarting the service manually it works fine.

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Sounds like you're not forcing a required dependency, so something is missing at first, starting after your service.

Comment: Maybe. It needs the MS SQL Server wich also runs on that server. I changed my service to start automatic(delayed start). But I cannot try yet, because im not allowed to reboot the server. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then the SQL Server service should be an dependency or your program should wait for it. That's most likely the culprit. If that doesn't help, try logging.